# PrintDocument: Impressão demorando muito no IIS

Tags: c#, web-service, impressora

Estou com um projeto de automação (Web Service) onde uma das funções é imprimir um arquivo de texto (simples) lado servidor.

Esse Web Service chama uma dll composta por um objeto "PrintDocument" e após adicionar algumas linhas via "e.Graphics.DrawString", envia o conteúdo para impressora através do método "PrinterName".

Tudo funciona bem, mas com um pequeno detalhe: Quando o Web service chama essa dll, demora de 1 a 3 minutos para imprimir.

No início achei que poderia ser minha rotina, então fiz um projeto Windows Forms utilizando a mesma dll e o tempo de impressão não demorou quase nada, alguns segundos apenas.

Já tentei de tudo, revirei a internet e não encontrei nada a respeito.

Comment: Seu projeto Windows Forms que você fez estava executando no mesmo servidor ou local?

Comment: Sim, fiz um aplicativo Win Forms de testes e executei no mesmo servidor que está o Ws. A diferença de tempo foi absurda. Imprimiu em questão de segundos.

Comment: Tem como posta a sua rotina que chama a dll?

Comment: Sem a rotina para testar e o tempo que levou para ser elaborada a edição(09/04/2016) recomendo a exclusão.